# Jquery Mobile - Edit Icon

Tags: jquery-mobile

I currently have a jquery page where I am using Delete and Edit icons.
For the delete icon, I am using:

```
      data-icon="delete"
```

For the edit icon, I am using

```
     data-icon="plus"
```

Just wondering what the standard icon is for edit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is :

```
data-icon="edit"
```

But you will need to use at least jQuery Mobile 1.3 to have it available.

Working **jsFiddle** example: http://jsfiddle.net/4z64J/

Comment: Used to use "grid" to open an "editing form" - Hadn't realized this got added.  Very nice.

Comment: If I can remember it correctly developers added it because users pressured them to add it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not a default icon for edit. 
Maybe I would also use `data-icon="plus"` or  `data-icon="gear"`.

If you want you can use a custom icon.

http://andymatthews.net/code/jQuery-Mobile-Icon-Pack/font-awesome/ - This is a nice pack (data-icon="pencil" would do the work for you, I think.)

Regards!

> P.S. I have read what Gajotres answered. It is great that this icon is added in jQuery Mobile latest! Thanks for the info!